# To Envelope or Envelop a Letter?

Tags: verbs

I understand that Envelope is the noun and Envelop is the verb but, as I understand it, the verb envelop has more to do with the literally and figuratively surrounding of something.

If I’m enveloping a letter, what do I use? For example, I’m trying to describe a service where I will “Write, Envelope, and Post” a letter, is it envelope or envelop in this case?

Comment: We use *envelope* as a verb in some IT contexts, same metaphorical meaning as putting a paper letter in an envelope.

Answer (score 1):

> If I’m enveloping a letter, what do I use?

You do **not** use "to envelop."

OED:

> **2. To wrap, cover closely on all sides with a surrounding medium (e.g. clouds, darkness, flames, an atmosphere, etc.). Const. in, with. Also with the surrounding medium as subject.**
>
> 1847   L. Hunt Jar of Honey (1848) ii. 15   *One of these cliffs towers to such a height, that its summit is for ever enveloped in clouds.*

The subject of the verb to envelop does the action:

"A dark mist enveloped the castle." - it is the dark mist that does the action of enveloping.

In "I envelop the letter." this means that you yourself would surround the letter on all sides or wrap yourself around the letter.

I suggest,

> I will “Write a/the letter, put it in an envelope, and post it”.

However, it is hardly worth adding "put it in an envelope" as this would naturally be assumed because nobody sends open letters in the post.

Comment: We can say both "the rug covered the floor" and "I covered the floor with a blanket". You could also say something like "the fall of night enveloped the house in darkness". That said, I agree that the idiomatic expression for OP's situation is "put the letter in an envelope".